# How is it possible to combine rafael.js and paper.js in one html?

Tags: javascript, paperjs, rafaeljs

While I was trying to use two libraries (rafael.js and paper.js) in one html page, I got various errors.

Case 1. Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined. In the file "rafael.js", the line:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 320, 200);
```

was the reason of the error. But obviously it is imported in html:

```
<head>
...
<script src="js/paper-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mypaper.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/rafael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id='myCanvas' resize></canvas>
<script src="js/myrafael.js"></script>
...
</body>
```

Case 2. paper.js output: Uncaught Error: Unable to find canvas with id "myCanvas", but the canvas is there. Here is html:

```
<head>
...
<script src="js/rafael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/paper-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mypaper.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='myCanvas' resize></canvas>
<script src="js/myrafael.js"></script>
...
</body>
```

The same error also happened when I had rafael and paper code in one .js file ("myrafaelpaper.js") despite the fact that myCanvas is there:

```
<head>
...
<script src="js/rafael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/paper-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/myrafaelpaper.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='myCanvas' resize></canvas>
<script src="js/myrafaelpaper.js"></script>
...
</body>
```

Separately, they work fine.

"myrafaelpaper.js" is here:

```
//rafael.js part
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 320, 200);
var circle = paper.circle(0, 30, 50);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
console.log(circle.isPointInside(50, 30));

//paper.js part
var pathData = 'M100,50c0,27.614-22.386,50-50,50S0,77.614,0,50S22.386,0,50,0S100,22.386,100,50';
var path = new Path(pathData);
path.strokeColor = 'red';
path.strokeWidth = 5;
path.position+= new Point(100, 50);
path.segments[3].point.selected=true;
```

The content of "myrafael.js" and "mypaper.js" are analogical.

Comment: Post your JavaScript.

Comment: why the `<script src=''>` tag is in the body ?

Comment: Isnt it allowed? It does not cause the issue unless these libraries are combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of the cases you've mentioned, the script-tag for `myrafaelpaper.js` is not closed (`</script>`).

Comment: But there is "<script src="js/myrafaelpaper.js"></script>", isn't it?

Comment: Correct, but in your post, you can see that "</head><body><script src=" isn't styled, so maybe the browser also doesn't recognize the rest of your script?

Comment: What do u mean "styled"? Have no idea why it is put in different colours in the post, but as far as I know even if I put everything in one line in a notepad, it still should work because the browser reads and interprets the tags, and what is inside and between them, not the colours or other styles. Did I miss smt?

Comment: Exactly, they are different colors. That's because you didn't close one of the script-tags. Try doing that and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: yes, now I see it. I though I closed everything. I will check on the server later.

Comment: Closing "<script src="js/mypaper.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">" with "</script>" solved the issue.